# python mysql error 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: python-2.7, mysql-python

I'm trying to excute a mysql query but I get the following error:

```
(1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'C:/wamp/www/dle/uploads/posts/2013-08/1376251255-IMG11111674.jpg" >\n            \' at line 3')
```

this is my python code I want to excute:

```
image_p_add = """
                <div>
                <!--TBegin:%s|-->
                <a href=\"%s\" onclick=\"return hs.expand(this)\" >
                <img src=\"%s\" alt=\"%s\" title=\"%s\"  />
                </a>
                <!--TEnd-->
                </div><br /><br />
                """ % (img_fulladd.replace("_", "\_"), img_fulladd.replace("_", "\_"), thumb_fulladd.replace("_", "\_"), post_header[1:-1], post_header[1:-1])
post_shrt_text = "some text" + image_p_add
qu0 = """INSERT INTO dle_post (category, short_story)
                VALUES
                    ('1', %s)""" % (post_shrt_text)
cur.execute(qu0)
```

I checked my code a lot and almost sure that there is no missed quotes.

`img_fulladd` and `thumb_fulladd` are some image addresses like :

```
C:/wamp/www/dle/uploads/posts/2013-08/1376251255-IMG11111674.jpg
```

`post_header` is some text for header within double quotes

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: There seems to be something missing in your question, since your code example doesn't seem to include any MySQL calls. Can you show the part of the code where you actually execute the SQL query? It looks like your problem would be helped by using prepared statements, but it's hard to give a good example without seeing the code you already have.

Comment: @MartinAtkins sry for short code, I completed my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Letting the MySQLdb driver do the parameter insertion for you should give better results.

```
cur.execute(
    "INSERT INTO dle_post (category, short_story) VALUES ('1', %s)", (
        post_shrt_text,
    )
)
```

It's good to let the driver handle this because it knows how to safely insert a string into the query without allowing for SQL injection.